# PHPMailer works on one page but doesn't work on similar

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

EDIT: Somehow the code only works on the webserver and not on localhost, so there's your "fix".

So, my php code works as it should like this:

```
  require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  $nome = $_POST["nome"];
  $subject = $_POST["subject"];
  $message = $_POST["message"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $contacto = $_POST["contacto"];
  $body = "<p>Mail recebido de: </p>" . $nome . "<p>Email:</p>" . $email . "<p> Contacto:</p>" . $contacto . "<p>Mensagem:</p>" . $message ;
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->CharSet = "text/html; charset=UTF-8;";
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
  $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->Port = 587;
  $mail->Username = "the email";
  $mail->Password = the password;
  $mail->SetFrom('the email', 'Organizer');
  $mail->Subject = "[ORÇAMENTO] " . $subject;
  $mail->Body = $body;
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->AddAddress("the email");
  if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  $sucesso = 'Mensagem enviada com sucesso!';
}
```

this first script sends the email to itself, but even that doesn't work here ($mail->Send() = 1, still I don't receive the email):

```
require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
          $body = "<p>Car(a) " . ${'user' . $i} . ",</p> <p> Foi lhe associado(a) uma nova ocorrência. Consulte-a em http://www.organizer.com.pt . </p>";
          $mail = new PHPMailer();
          $mail->CharSet = "text/html; charset=UTF-8;";
          $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
          $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
          $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
          $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
          $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
          $mail->Port = 587;
          $mail->Username = "the email";
          $mail->Password = the password;
          $mail->SetFrom('the email', 'Organizer');
          $mail->Subject = "Nova Ocorrência";
          $mail->Body = $body;
          $mail->IsHTML(true);
          $mail->AddAddress($email);
          if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
          } else {
            $sucesso = 'Mensagem enviada com sucesso!';
          }
```

I have tested all the variables that I get from the database and so on and they are all correct, I just don't receive the email for some reason. Anyone can help?

P.S.: Sorry some of this is in portuguese, I think the code is still perfectly understandable.

Comment: Any error message ?

Comment: nope, supposedly the mail is sent, that's why I dont understand.

Comment: Check In Script 2...Is it "require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';" OR "require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';"

Comment: that is correct, the directory is different, or I would just get a "normal" error anyways.

Comment: Is $email defined in second script ?

Comment: yes, like I said all the variables are correct (I printed them mid script to be sure), $email is defined just some lines before.

Comment: Have you tried sending to/from a different email address ?

Comment: Just For A Try......Copy PHPMailer Folder To Folder where 2nd script is...And try require'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'; It is just for checking if issue is related to phpmailer or in coding...

Comment: tried both of your anwsers, none worked :(

Comment: for some reason the script on this specific page only worked on the webserver and not on localhost.

Comment: Your local mail serve isn't properly configured or your ISP or remote mail server is blocking your connection.

Answer (score 0):

"Doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. On SO, detail is everything.

It doesn't help that you've based your code on an obsolete & incorrect example and have not read the docs, and I suspect you are using an old version of PHPMailer too since it would have provided you with a link to relevant docs if it was a recent version. So before anything else, [get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki).

As for specific problems: `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` with `Port = 587` will not work. Port 587 is used for SMTP+STARTTLS, not implicit SSL, so set `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`.

This is just wrong:

```
$mail->CharSet = "text/html; charset=UTF-8;";
```

Your other script does it right:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

If you're having trouble with something that has a debug option, enable it!

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

Increase that to 3 if you have initial connection problems.

I'd like to know where you got that example code so I can ask the authors to delete or update it; having broken, obsolete examples lying around just wastes everybody's time.